# php: Unable to update a "lastseen" record on DB

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need to update a "last seen" record on database, every time a user logs in. I create the us_lastseen record (type DATETIME), with no positive result.

After trying to change its type to VARCHAR, it neither records the actual time so I guess the error is on the piece of code:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$lastSeen= mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen=$now WHERE us_id=$user_id");
```

I have also tried:

```
$lastSeen= mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen=GETDATE() WHERE us_id=$user_id");
```

Comment: Are you using mySql ?

Comment: Try `echo "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen=GETDATE() WHERE us_id=$user_id"` and copy past result in mysql queries interface to make sure that the problem is not in query.

Comment: I have changed the query for "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen="1111-11-11 11:11:11" WHERE us_id=$user_id" and it has changed c orrectly the date. When echoed, the original query says "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen=Array WHERE us_id=2"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `DATETIME` type and the following code :

```
$lastSeen= mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen=NOW() WHERE us_id=$user_id");
```

Or add quotes :

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$lastSeen= mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE ws_users SET us_lastseen='$now' WHERE us_id=$user_id");
```

You should debug your query and execute it to see if it throws an error (using phpmyadmin i.e.)

Comment: Thank you. I always echo the query and try on Phphmyadmin in case of issue, but this operation is made on a file that just opens the session and moves the user to and specific panel depending on his/her role. So it does not stop a second on there. Neither FIREBUG stores the echoed result (even on KEEP option activated), so I do not find any other possibility for debugging this.

Comment: Worked. Ill tick in 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. You can `exit;` just after your `echo` to see your query